# Identify this place in Myanmar

Tags: identify-this, architecture, myanmar

I'm trying to identify this Myanmar place.

[image]

This appears in a local (Spanish) travel magazine promoting a Myanmar trip but doesn't have a legend. Do you know where is it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Getty Images](http://www.gettyimages.com.au/pictures/the-giant-reclining-buddha-of-the-zinathukha-pagoda-news-photo-175109507):

> The giant reclining Buddha of the Zinathukha pagoda surrounded by the jungle and stupas. This reclining Buddha, of which the concrete structure is 200 metres long and 40 metres high and the unfinished construction started in 1992, is reportedly the largest of its kind in the world.

This in the town of [Mudon, Mon State, Myanmar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudon).

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9mWD405stU

Comment: Just wanted to add that the place looks completely different these days. They deforested much of the area and are currently building a second reclining Buddha, so the place rather looks like a big construction site.